# Train/ Test split on small dataset along with SMOTE

Tags: xgboost, training, class-imbalance, smote

I have a binary classification imbalanced dataset with 1000 samples ( 15% of class 1, 85% of the rest). My main goal is to build a robust classifier using the following approach. Wanted to know if there are potential downsides for the same when using a Tree classifier or if there is another way to tackle the same:

1. Do a 40/60 split of the data, use SMOTE to increase the Training dataset, and train the model
2. Test it out on the 60% test data( the main reason is that we are trying to make recommendations and larger sample size on the test data will invoke more confidence)

There is not a way to collect more samples for the experiment here. Is there another approach that could solve the issue of low sample on the test data. We just want to be sure the results are robust enough on the bigger test dataset.

Thank you

Comment: 50/50 without smote is what I would do

Comment: @NikosM. So 50% training and then use SMOTE on that set to develop the model. Should I cross-validation along with SMOTE to make sure we are sampling the training dataset well and the model is robust?

Comment: At least 50% of the data should be used for training. Now I **would not** use artificial oversampling (eg SMOTE) at least not without first checking if the **original data alone are sufficient**. Cross validation is an option

Comment: @NikosM. Okay makes sense. Is there a reason potential downsides of using SMOTE for upsampling the training data? Also in your experience is XGboost a good model to run on a ~1000 sample of data

Comment: oversampling is not magic, it has downsides, for example it can skew the data, introduce bias and so on. So use it wisely. XGBoost seems fine, but the final results will dictate the best option

Comment: Makes sense. Another question I had was that will the feature importances after performing SMOTE on the training dataset be trustable as we are introducing synthetic samples here?

Comment: I cannot answer that without knowing details and even then it depends. It is possible though

Comment: In your `train_test_split`, you could use `stratify=True` before applying SMOTE. This will ensure that both datasets will have the same proportion (15:85) of classes